# NSNumber how to get smallest common denominator? Like 3/8 for 0.375?

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm, nsnumber

Say if I have an NSNumber, which is something between 0 and 1, and it can be represented using X/Y, how do I calculate the X and Y in this case? I don't want to compare:

```
if (number.doubleValue == 0.125)
{
    X = 1;
    Y = 8;
}
```

so I get 1/8 for 0.125

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's relatively straightforward. For example, `0.375` is equivalent to `0.375/1`.

First step is to multiply numerator and denominator until the numerator is an integral value <sup>(a)</sup>, giving you `375/1000`.

Then find the greatest common divisor and divide both numerator and denominator by that.

A (recursive) function for GCD is:

```
int gcd (int a, int b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd (b, a%b);
}
```

If you call that with `375` and `1000`, it will spit out `125` so that, when you divide the numerator and denominator by that, you get `3/8`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As pointed out in the comments, there may be problems with numbers that have more precision bits than your integer types (such as IEEE754 doubles with 32-bit integers). You can solve this by choosing integers with a larger range (longs, or a bignum library like MPIR) or choosing a "close-enough" strategy (consider it an integer when the fractional part is relatively insignificant compared to the integral part).

Another issue is the fact that some numbers don't even *exist* in IEEE754, such as the infamous `0.1` and `0.3`.

Unless a number can be represented as the sum of `2-n` values where `n` is limited by the available precision (such as `0.375` being `1/4 + 1/8`), the best you can hope for is an approximation.

Example, consider the single-precision (you'll see why below, I'm too lazy to do the whole 64 bits) `1/3`. As a single precision value, this is stored as:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 01111101 01010101010101010101010
```

In this example, the sign is `0` hence it's a positive number.

The exponent bits give 125 which, when you subtract the 127 bias, gives you -2. Hence the multiplier will be `2-2`, or `0.25`.

The mantissa bits are a little trickier. They form the sum of an explicit `1` along with all the `2-n` values for the `1` bits, where `n` is 1 through 23 (left to right. So the mantissa is calculated thus:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 01111101 01010101010101010101010
            | | | | | | | | | | |
            | | | | | | | | | | +-- 0.0000002384185791015625
            | | | | | | | | | +---- 0.00000095367431640625
            | | | | | | | | +------ 0.000003814697265625
            | | | | | | | +-------- 0.0000152587890625
            | | | | | | +---------- 0.00006103515625
            | | | | | +------------ 0.000244140625
            | | | | +-------------- 0.0009765625
            | | | +---------------- 0.00390625
            | | +------------------ 0.015625
            | +-------------------- 0.0625
            +---------------------- 0.25
                           Implicit 1
                                    ========================
                                    1.3333332538604736328125
```

When you multiply that by `0.25` (see exponent earlier), you get:

```
0.333333313465118408203125
```

Now *that's* why they say you only get about 7 decimal digits of precision (15 for IEEE754 double precision).

Were you to pass that actual number through my algorithm above, you would not get `1/3`, you would instead get:

```
 5,592,405
---------- (or 0.333333313465118408203125)
16,777,216
```

But that's not a problem with the algorithm per se, more a limitation of the numbers you can represent.

Thaks to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) for helping out with the calculations. If you ever need to do *any* math that stresses out your calculator, that's one of the best tools for the job.

---

> As an aside, you'll no doubt notice the mantissa bits follow a certain pattern: `0101010101...`. This is because `1/3` is an infinitely recurring binary value as well as an infinitely recurring decimal one. You would need and infinite number of `01` bits at the end to exactly represent `1/3` exactly.

Comment: But that doesn't work if the number is 0.4, since 1/0.4 is 2.5, which isn't an integer.

Comment: @Riley, wrong way around, you want `0.4/1`. This turns into `4/10` which has a GCD of `2` so that division then gives you `2/5`.

Comment: Or even 0.3750000000000000001 (since it is stored as a double).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yes, in the world of pure maths. Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on your POV), the real world has limits on precision. In any case, you can just modify your definition of integer to be "close enough" :-)

Comment: I think what he was getting at though, is that you are going to end up with a really big number that can't be reduced as your numerator in this case.

Comment: @lnafziger, see prev. comment. If you want more precision then yes, you'll need integers with a bigger range, such as by using MPIR. The GCD algorithm will still hold.

Comment: @paxdiablo Exactly. Your answer won't provide him with exact values, which is what I was saying.

Comment: It will provide an answer within the limitations of the data types supported. That's usually the best you can hope for, given the limits we work under. If you have extra information, such as the fact that you're only working with `x` significant digits, it's easy to limit the multiplications to suit.

Comment: @paxdiablo So, how would you actually write the code for something like this? Your way wouldn't be as efficient, since you would need to multiply the numerator and denominator by every possible value in order to ensure int values (as per your edits) and then you would still have to find the gcd and divide, which is less efficient than what I wrote.

Comment: @Riley, not sure what you're getting at, you don't multiply by every value, you multiply by 10 a small number of times. For example, the `0.375` only needs three multiplications to get to `375/1000`, then four levels of recursion to get the `125` gcd, then two more divisions to get `3/8`.

Comment: @paxdiablo Okay. And when you have 1/3? And 1/17? And 1/41?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19457/discussion-between-paxdiablo-and-rileye)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
- (CGPoint)yourXAndYValuesWithANumber:(NSNumber *)number
{
    float x = 1.0f;
    float y = x/number.doubleValue;
    for(int i = 1; TRUE; i++)
    {
        if((float)(int)(y * i) == y * i)
        // Alternatively floor(y * i), instead of (float)(int)(y * i)
        {
            x *= i;
            y *= i;
            break;
        }
    }
    /* Also alternatively
    int coefficient = 1;
    while(floor(y * coefficient) != y * coefficient)coefficient++;
    x *= coefficient, y *= coefficient;*/
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

This will not work if you have invalid input. X and Y will have to exist and be valid natural numbers (1 to infinity). A good example that will break it is 1/pi. If you have limits, you can do some critical thinking to implement them.

Comment: I tried this and got a **really** long loop and nothing but 0, 0, with various values....

Comment: @lnafziger What value did you use?

Comment: I tried 0.375 since that was the original question.  Then 0.250 and 4.0 just in case I misunderstood something here, lol:  `NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.375];
    CGPoint point = [self yourXAndYValuesWithANumber:number];
    NSLog(@"%f/%f", point.x, point.y);`

Comment: I'm sorry. I had a typo. I wrote this in SO, so I screwed up the bracket. Try it now.

Comment: Haha, I hate that.  Works beautifully now.  +1

Comment: @lnafziger Or if people are more particular to while loops, I made a slight edit/addition.

Comment: Although, it worked great for the first few numbers but it's been churning away for a couple of minutes (on a Macbook Pro) with 1/17 and still no answer yet.

Comment: @lnafziger Really? I plugged it into XCode now and I used this: `NSLog(@"Point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([self yourXAndYValuesWithANumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0f/17.0f]]));` and I got: Point: {1, 17}

Comment: Haha, I figured out why:  Better check for 0 or you'll end up in an endless loop.  :)

Comment: @lnafziger Oh. This will only work with an actual answer. If there isn't an answer, it will check nearly infinitely. This is best for specific uses (when you know that x and y are real values) and in CS class.

Comment: You should probably put some kind of safety net in there that abandons the attempt if it goes through too many iterations then..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19458/discussion-between-rileye-and-lnafziger)

Answer (score 0):

The approach outlined by paxdiablo is spot-on.

I just wanted to provide an efficient GCD function (implemented iteratively):

```
int gcd (int a, int b){
    int c;
    while ( a != 0 ) {
        c = a; a = b%a; b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

[Source](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/mfmm/compaa/gcd.c).